# Can not print Latex glossaries section in TexStudio

Tags: latex, glossary, texstudio

It seems there is something wrong with my compile or build settings in my Texstudio. I can not get the glossary list to output from the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a markup language specially suited for 
        scientific documents}
}


\newglossaryentry{formula}
{
    name=formula,
    description={A mathematical expression}
}

\begin{document}
    
    The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
    for documents that include \gls{maths}. \Glspl{formula} are rendered 
    properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.
    
    \clearpage
    
    \printglossary[title=Special Terms, toctitle=List of terms]
    
\end{document}
```

My current output is:
[image]

My Texstudio command settings are:
[image]

With my build settings :
[image]

Please help

I have looked at nearly every link on google and tried several solutions and can not get the glossaries to print as a glossary list.

One example:[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156270/has-anyone-managed-to-use-glossaries-with-texstudio-on-windows#:~:text=The%20problem%20may%20be%20because,%22Commands%22%20option%20in%20TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156270/has-anyone-managed-to-use-glossaries-with-texstudio-on-windows#:%7E:text=The%20problem%20may%20be%20because,%22Commands%22%20option%20in%20TexStudio).

but none of the options on any stack website work for me.

One of the messages I am getting in the message panel of Texstudio is:

> This is makeindex, version 2.16 [MiKTeX 23.5]. Scanning style file C:/Users/66smi/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist............done (12 attributes redefined, 3 ignored). Scanning input file MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.nlo....
> done (7 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Sorting entries....done (23 comparisons). Generating output file MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.nls....done (13 lines written, 0 warnings). Output written in MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.nls. Transcript written in MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.ilg.
> Process exited normally

I Have a tentative answer, by installing `perl` as suggested by:
[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410606/texmaker-makeglossaries-the-script-engine-could-not-be-found)

But I am still getting the following error message

> Unable to fork "makeindex" with redirection No such file or directory Retrying without redirection.
> This is makeindex, version 2.16 [MiKTeX 23.5]. Scanning style file ./MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.ist.....................
> ......done (27 attributes redefined, 0 ignored). Scanning input file MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.acn....done (17 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Sorting entries....done (84 comparisons). Generating output file MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.acr....done (12 lines written, 0 warnings). Output written in MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.acr. Transcript written in MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.alg.
> Unable to fork "makeindex" with redirection No such file or directory
> Unable to fork "makeindex" with redirection No such file or directory Retrying without redirection.
> This is makeindex, version 2.16 [MiKTeX 23.5]. Scanning style file ./MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.ist...........................done (27 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
> Scanning input file MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.acn....done (17 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Sorting entries....done (84 comparisons). Generating output file MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.acr....done (12 lines written, 0 warnings). Output written in MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.acr. Transcript written in MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.alg.
> Unable to fork "makeindex" with redirection No such file or directory
> Warning: File 'MSS732_Final Report_Smith J_19065320.glo' is empty. Have you used any entries defined in glossary 'main'? Remember to use package option 'nomain' if you don't want to use the main glossary.
> Process exited normally

I will add/finalize the solution once i resolve the above message

Comment: Your example works fine for me, did you run `makeglossaries your_file_name`? (to be found in the menu bar->`tools`->`Glossary` or press `F9`) Do you get any errors in the "Messages" tab when you run makeglossaries?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have updated the description with one of the messages I am getting. It says something about the "perl" package

I just went ```pip install perl``` in my command center but that didnt help

Comment: pip is for Python; Perl is a different language. `cpan` is the installer for Perl modules, normally. However, your TeX setup (Texlive?) probably includes whatever is needed. AFAIK on Windows there is Strawberry Perl. On Unix, use your package manager to install everything you need.

Comment: What message regarding Perl do you get? Always include the actual error message, "something about Perl" is not helpful.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163794/makeindex-warning about the fork warning; it's harmless. But I think you need to run `makeglossaries yourfile`, not `makeindex`. Did you run `makeglossaries` somehow? What happened? (I don't use TeXStudio, so I don't know how to hook that up.)

Comment: @JustinSmith Can you try only running pdflatex, then makeglossaries, then pdflatex again? (not makeindex)

Comment: @Robert, i am only running ```makeglossaries``` and ```makeindex``` as i initially had an issue with my nomenclature section (the ```nomencl``` package) where I had to use ```makeindex```. I will fiddle around with that now too